# Ambiguity between property and event in vb6 com server

Tags: c#, com, vb6, ambiguity

In my c# project, I'm referncing an old com server written in vb6. When tyring to access a property "ModuleLoaded" (meaning "IsModuleLoaded"), I get an ambiguity warning because the server also defines an event with the same name. My code looks like this:

```
if (fwb.Controller.ModuleLoaded == false) {
  fwb.Controller.LoadModule();
}
```

Visual Studio tells me this:

```
Error: Ambiguity between "MCS._clsController.ModuleLoaded" and
"MCS.__clsController_Event.ModuleLoaded".
```

How can I resolve the ambiguity without changing code in the com server itself?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to cast to the generated containing interface;

```
if (((MCS._clsController)fwb.Controller).ModuleLoaded == false) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your help -"((MCS._clsController)fwb.Controller).ModuleLoaded" did the trick!